# Form field Validation custom email requirements

Tags: php, regex, validation, email

Looking to create a form validation on email text field.
Have previously used validation to ensure correct email is produced.

But here looking to create a more custom rule which allows only emails ending in the format .ac.uk

Here a user would be able to provide any university/college/instituion as long as the last 6 characters in the string = .ac.uk with the general format for the mail as follows: `email@university.ac.uk`

Solution preferably in PHP, currently looking at employing a rule using the end part in this statement:

```
^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$
```

Making this part `*(\.[a-z]{2,3})` relate to the `.ac.uk`

many thanks, much appreciated
Jeanclaude

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want us to write a email validator that meets your demands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first run the email through `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` rather than using a simple regex.  It's not perfect (I've found a few edge cases that don't validate correctly) but it works well.  Once you know it's a valid email address you can simply trust `substr($email, -6) == '.ac.uk'` and be done with it.  Something like:

```
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) 
    && strtolower(substr(trim($email), -6))) === '.ac.uk') {

    // Valid
}
```

Comment: (FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL is internally also implemented as regex.)

Comment: Oh that's interesting.  I'm assuming then it's one of those extremely elaborate regex's.  I still trust it over the average regex I often see used, like the one in this post.

Comment: It's indeed: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/filter/logical_filters.c#L500 There are [more elaborate ones](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1917982/345031) of course, which fully covered rfc2822. But it's sufficient for most cases.

Comment: Ok nice one, Thank you i will try this approach using substr($email, -6) == '.ac.uk' and see how it works.